# Plotting points on one line in python. 1 dimension

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

This is the kind of graph that I would like to plot, without y axis . How can I achieve this in python using matplotlib if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there is not built-in fonction in `matplotlib` to create such a graph.

However, You can use the following code to have a similar output. This snippet is removing unwanted spines (left, right and top) and then using scatterplot to simulate a 1d graph.

As Follows:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,1))

x = [1,2,3,4,9,10]
idx = np.arange(1,len(x)+1)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_alpha(0.2)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.set_xlabel('Gene 1')
ax.scatter(x, np.zeros(len(x)), s=300, c='lightgreen')
ax.set_xticks([min(x), max(x)], ['Low Values', 'High Values'])
      
for i in range(len(idx)):
    ax.annotate(idx[i], (x[i], 0), textcoords="offset points",
                xytext=(0,0), # distance from text to points (x,y)
                ha='center')
plt.show()
```

Outputs:

[image]